# help in c++ mfc dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

i need help knowing how to post up a message in mfc project. but i need to do it in a class which is not the dialog class.

i need it to check some values in another class and i want to be able to write some message in a window or something just to check some values
im hope my explanation was clear.
thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send/post a message you can use (A) the `CWnd` methods `SendMessage()`/`PostMessage()` or (B) the `::SendMessage()` / `::PostMessage()` functions.
This can be done from anywhere, i.e. you can also send messages from non-window classes. The only thing you need is the target CWnd object (case A) or the handle of its window (case B).

Answer (score 0):

No, your question is not clear. Please try to explain better what you want to do.

This is how you post a message to a window (assuming you have a CWnd reference to your window):

```
m_MyWnd.PostMessage(WM_APP, 0x1234, 0x4567);
```